# How to check Request/Response Body in Blazemeter Test?

Tags: jmeter, httprequest, performance-testing, httpresponse, blazemeter

I was wondering if there is a way to check Request/Response body for transactions (real-time/post test) in Blazemeter.
I can see there's a "Log" section, but I'd love to know if there's a way to log request/response body for pass or fail transactions for analysis purpose.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD5Wr.jpg)

Regards!

I've tried exploring the Blazemeter tool with no result.
Tired to google for answer but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you have [`jmeter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jmeter) in your tags I assume you're running a JMeter test.

In this case in BlazeMeter's [Logs Report](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13261977460881-Logs-Report#h_b67e50b6-4b3e-498f-8b6d-8261ee2fb23d) there will be *error.jtl* file

[image]

It contains request and response details for failed requests, you can download the file and open it with JMeter's [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and see all the information:

[image]